# SQL while loop for fortnightly data

Tags: sql, while-loop

Good morning,

I have some code, which works perfectly well, but I wanted to know if this could be optimised to run on a while-loop somehow. Basically I want a count per site done on a fortnightly basis, starting from the declared startdate and enddate which is the first fortnight. It would run up until the most recent Sunday. Code below.

```
DECLARE @Startdate DATE SET @Startdate = '2022-03-14'

DECLARE @enddate DATE
SET @enddate =  (select DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 13, @Startdate )+13, +13))


Select SiteName
      ,COUNT ( CASE WHEN CallDate between @Startdate and @enddate THEN CaseID END) as 'Period 1'
      ,COUNT ( CASE WHEN CallDate between  DATEADD(DD,14,@Startdate) and DATEADD(DD, 14 ,@enddate) THEN CaseID END) as 'Period 2'
      ,COUNT ( CASE WHEN CallDate between  DATEADD(DD,28,@Startdate) and DATEADD(DD, 28 ,@enddate) THEN CaseID END) as 'Period 3'
      ,COUNT ( CASE WHEN CallDate between  DATEADD(DD,28,@Startdate) and DATEADD(DD, 28 ,@enddate) THEN CaseID END) as 'Period 4'

FROM [PathwaysDos_LIVE].[dbo].[vwCases]
where SiteTypeID = 5

group by SiteName
```

Thanks in advance,

Regards, Andrew.

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: SQL server management studio 18

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calendar table. For example, creating it on the fly

```
DECLARE @Startdate DATE SET @Startdate = '2022-03-14';

with t0(n) as (
 select n 
 from (
    values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
    ) t(n)
), ns as (
   select row_number() over(order by t1.n) - 1 n
   from t0 t1, t0 t2, t0 t3
), calendar as (
   select DATEADD(D, n*14, @Startdate) ds,  DATEADD(D, n*14 + 13 ,@Startdate) de
   from ns
   where DATEADD(D, n*14, @Startdate) < getdate()
)
select SiteName, ds, de
      ,COUNT ( CASE WHEN CallDate between ds and de THEN CaseID END) as 'Period 1'
      ,COUNT ( CASE WHEN CallDate between  DATEADD(DD, 14, ds) and DATEADD(DD, 14, de) THEN CaseID END) as 'Period 2'
      ,COUNT ( CASE WHEN CallDate between  DATEADD(DD, 28, ds) and DATEADD(DD, 28, de) THEN CaseID END) as 'Period 3'
      ,COUNT ( CASE WHEN CallDate between  DATEADD(DD, 28, ds) and DATEADD(DD, 28, de) THEN CaseID END) as 'Period 4'
from calendar
join [PathwaysDos_LIVE].[dbo].[vwCases] 
  on SiteTypeID = 5 and CallDate between ds and DATEADD(DD, 28, de)
group by SiteName, ds, de;
```